# Finder API list ACA Approved Health Insurance API JSON?

Tags: data-format, healthcare-finder-api

Does Healthcare.gov or Finder API list ACA Approved Health Insurance in API JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

Data.healthcare.gov has simple JSON (and XML and CSV, for that matter) APIs to search the Qualified Health Plans for the ACA at https://data.healthcare.gov/browse?limitTo=datasets -- simply click into a dataset, click "Export", "SODA API", and "API docs"

Quick screencast showing how to get from data catalog to API docs and a simple JSON query: http://recordit.co/GnrjnhLBDl

Comment: Fixed link.. I think. Is this what you were looking for?